# External tables privilages

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Though the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#external-table-privileges) says only SELECT and OWNERSHIP can be granted on external tables, I succeed in granting REFERENCES. This is allows our monitoring role to check EXTERNAL_TABLE_FILE_REGISTRATION_HISTORY for those tables.

Is the documentation wrong? Or this is bug/feature?

EDIT:
The command I run:
`GRANT REFERENCES ON EXTERNAL TABLE schema.ext_table TO role;`

Comment: Can you post the command you run to give the grant?

Comment: Thanks for filling the case with Snowflake Support. We will look into details!. Thanks, FK

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#external-table-privileges
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-intro.html#required-access-privileges